# Paramiko ssh connection without password

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

Currently I am logging in to the Unix server from my Windows desktop by giving a password in ssh.connect. Is there a way I can avoid giving the password?

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ltc02.force.com',username = 'user',password = 'pwd')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use public key authentication using a private key that has no password.

The general process is you create a new key on the client machine using

> ssh-keygen -t rsa

Then you upload your public key to the server, copy paste it into  :

> .ssh/authorized_keys

The .ssh directory will be located in your user home directory on the server.

Of course, because your private key has no password you need to ensure you take adequate steps to protect it.

Note that this is not a Python specific answer.  SSH Public Key is a standard process and the keys uses are standard RSA (or DSA) keys. So you should be able to do SSH public key authentication in any language of your choice.

Comment: any inputs on how to create and use these keys? I tried to install M2Crypto package in my Windows PC but failed

Comment: I believe there is a tool called PuTTYgen for windows.  And indeed, you can experiment getting public keys to work using the PuTTY SSH client for Windows.  There are pleanty of PuTTY tutorials out there on the internet (such as this one http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html)

Comment: i.e. Once you can get your SSH keys working in PuTTY, then you can move on to getting the keys to work with Python.

Comment: I will check Putty, but the pub/priv keys generated by Putty can be used in Python ?

Comment: Re:  the pub/priv keys generated by Putty can be used in Python ? .... yes, I just edited my original answer.  SSH public key authentication and the associated keys are a standardised thing... you should be able to do this in any language of your choosing (subject to libraries being available, or you coding your own).

Comment: No problem. I realised I should have made that clear before !